# Using a template for a custom admin page made with hook_menu

Tags: 7, routes, theming

I have developed a module in Drupal 7.

Now, I want to add a custom themed-page in the admin panel of Drupal.

I have added a page using `admin_menu()`:

```
function newsletter_menu()
{
    $info = array();

    $info['admin/reports/newsletter'] = array(
        "title" => "Number of Registered Users for Newsletter",
        "description" => "",
        "page callback" => "newsletter_admin_content_block",
        'page arguments' => array('newsletter_admin'),
        'access arguments' => array('administer newsletter settings'),
        'type' => MENU_NORMAL_ITEM
    );

    return $info;
}
```

It works all well. But my problem is:

I have a template file `newsletter.admin.tpl.php` which I want to use a the template for this page. But I don't know how should I achieve it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at this question on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305114/drupal-7-how-to-load-a-template-file-from-a-module

It basically comes down to this:

1. Implement [hook_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)
2. Create the template file
3. At the end of your `newsletter_admin_content_block` call `theme()` with your template key (as defined in `hook_theme()`) as first argument and any additional variables that you need in your template as an array.

Example:

```
function hook_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'newsletter_admin_content_template' => array(
      'variables' => array('var1' => NULL, 'var2' => NULL, ...),
      'template' => 'newsletter-admin-content-template'
    ),
  ),
}
```

And at the end of your menu callback:

```
return theme('newsletter_admin_content_template', array(
  'var1' => $var1,
  'var2' => $var2,
  ...
));
```

Comment: I have already implemented this technique, though it doesn't work. Seeing some other places on the net suggesting the same technique as yours, I know am sure that the problem is my code and not the technique itself.

Comment: Be sure to clear the cache. Also, do not add ".tpl.php" to the template name in `hook_theme()`. What else? There is also the question of where your template file is stored in your file system. For a custom module, it is logical to put it into your module directory and specify the `path`key in `hook_theme()`.

Comment: Yes it was a caching problem.

Answer (score 1):

you could try 
`page--admin--reports--newsletter.tpl.php` (refer to [Template Suggestions and Arguments](http://themery.com/sites/default/files/template-suggestions.pdf) for some more details).

Or just use a `theme_hook_suggestion`  (if really needed, with `hook_init()` and `menu_get_item()`).

In any case, be sure to place it in the templates folder of your theme and don't forget to clear the cache.